# How to include a definition language file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a big javascript file **common.js** 
with all my functions and stuff...and i would like to write a separate file Js 
to store only the definitions for all the alert/courtesy messages etc 
spread along the file...i don't want to seek and change one by one...

i have created something like this in php, where I have my file, en.php / fr.php /de.php for each language i need...

i was wondering:

**1. if i can do the same in Js**

**2. if there is any way to use the php instead...so woudl be even better to have just one and only file to edit**

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure -- all you need to do is to create a definitions file for each language that just creates an object with the needed `name: value` pairs. Your existing JS can then insert `defsObject["name"]` wherever needed. Your PHP would then determine which of the JS definition files to load by changing the `src` value of the script tag.

If you are unfamiliar with the object notation, there's loads of examples available on Stack Overflow ([tagged JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json)).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a satisfying way using js to include the definitions.